# How to prevent over engineering while try to achieve testable code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

In the following example, I want to test for the given source, if proper JSON is constructed and mapped into the returned object. At first, code had new Object creation inside it like this:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getAttributes( Source source, Response response )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( response, "response can not be null" );

    final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>( );

    final JSONArray users = new JSONArray( response.getEntityContentAsString( ) );
    final Set<String> mappedUsers = new HashSet<>( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < users.length( ); i++ )
    {
        mappedUsers.add( users.getJSONObject( i ).getString( "name" ) );
    }
    attributes.put( "mappedUsers", mappedUsers );

    return attributes;
}
```

But it has problems, first of all, I don't want to use PowerMock or other reflection utils to mock new object creation. But to test this code;

- I had to return proper JSON inside ***response.getEntityContentAsString( )*** because I didn't mock JSONArray, it should create proper object. This means I had to modify this 'dummy' json every time I want to test only this code behavior. I had to add the 'name' attribute inside the object or I had to make it proper length for the loop.

To prevent this I want to cover new object creation inside a factory. Now:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getAttributes( Source source, Response response )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( response, "response can not be null" );

    final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>( );

    final JSONArray users = jsonArrayFactory.create( response.getEntityContentAsString( ) );
    final Set<String> mappedUsers = new HashSet<>( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < users.length( ); i++ )
    {
        mappedUsers.add( users.getJSONObject( i ).getString( "name" ) );
    }
    attributes.put( "mappedUsers", mappedUsers );

    return attributes;
}
```

In my test, I can mock it instead of dealing custom JSON that works properly with the JSONArray class. Also, I don't have to deal with the implementation of the JSONArray since that library detail doesn't interest me in my function. But now it seems over-engineering because there are lots of cases like; JSONArray, JSONObject, JSONString, etc. in the project where they are created directly. Now team feels like they have to create all those factories JSONArrayFactory, JSONObjectFactory, etc.

What would you do in this example? May be we should change how we test the function? How do you deal with new object creations and prevent implementation details of 3rd parties?

Test of the given code:

```
@Test
public void getAttributes_givenResponse_shouldReturnAttributes( )
{
    final Response response = mock( Response.class );
    final JSONArray users = mock( JSONArray.class );
    final JSONObject user = mock( JSONObject.class );
    users.put( user );
    final String sampleContentEntity = "";
    final Integer sampleusersLength = 1;

    final String simpleName = "name";
    final Map<String, Object> expectedAttributes = new HashMap<>( );
    final Set<String> mappedUsers = new HashSet<>( );
    mappedUsers.add( simpleName );
    expectedAttributes.put( "mappedUsers", mappedUsers );

    when( response.getEntityContentAsString( ) ).thenReturn( sampleContentEntity );
    when( jsonArrayFactory.create( eq( sampleContentEntity ) ) ).thenReturn( users );
    when( users.length( ) ).thenReturn( sampleusersLength );
    when( users.getJSONObject( anyInt( ) ) ).thenReturn( user );
    when( user.getString( eq( "name" ) ) ).thenReturn( simpleName );

    final Map<String, Object> attributes =
        basicuserModule.getMappedAttributes( mock( Source.class ), response );

    assertThat( attributes ).isEqualTo( expectedAttributes );

    verify( response ).getEntityContentAsString( );
    verify( jsonArrayFactory ).create( eq( sampleContentEntity ) );
    verify( users ).getJSONObject( anyInt( ) );
}
```

Comment: Good rule of thumb: do not mock value objects. Use real JSONArrays and JSONObjects

Comment: Why not pass a `JSONArray` argument into the method rather than a `Response`? Your method should have a single responsibility, which seems to be "mapping a json structure to a (simple) Java model". Getting the JSON string from a Response and parsing it shouldn't be in there. As an added bonus, now your methods will also work with nested JSON structures where the users are deeper down in the data.

Comment: You both are right. Problem is with SRP, not factory itself. Than I will try how smooth it will be after your suggestions. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a compromise.

But this compromise works in both directions: If you use factories for everything, then yes, you'll be able to mock out pretty much everything, and you won't have any single "new" in a tested method, however, your test will look like a long series of mocks and it will be hard to read/understand/maintain the test, and its, IMO, a mandatory requirement from the test.

Another point to consider, its much better to have a black-box test than a white-box test.
In your case you don't return the `JSONArray users`, you just create it as an internal variable to do your **internal** calculations.

Now, ideally the test should check that given the list of input arguments the method returns the expected value, and that's it, the test should not fiddle with questions like "if I want to make it passing, I have to create the internal value here in this particular way, and then create another value like that". This all makes the test unclear and very fragile.

So Here are some "rules of thumb":

- Always prefer black box testing. Don't check what does the method internally do, ideally don't even look at the implementation of the class-under-test when you write the test.
- Always try to write methods that actually return something given the set of parameters
  This will make the test much easier to read and understand
- Mock/Stub only interactions - a real dependencies that the class requires. Usually there are not many of those, and they appear in very specific points. Don't mock internal variables creation, results of static calculations done in-place, or return value.

Examples:

```
// mocking example:
class SomeService {
    private SomeDAO dao; // this is a real dependency, mock it in test
}

// don't mock
Math.max(a,b)

// don't mock
LocalDateTime.of(...)

// don't mock
public int f() {
  ...
  List<Integer> internalVariable = new ArrayList<>(..)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Here are some questions: Since we will do blackbox-testing anyway in the upper levels of the testing pyramid (integration test, e2e test etc.), shouldn't we focus on whitebox testing in the unit test level?

Comment: Blackbox is better for any level of pyramid, including unit tests of course. The difference between all these types of tests is that they focus on checks at the different level: e2e checks business flow, integration checks a behaviour of component in a real/semi-real envrionment, unit - check the correctness of methods / classes, etc. All these tests should be as easy to understand as possible and black box testing helps to achieve this goal

Comment: But doesn't it force us to look into the implementation of JSONArray class, how it takes its input? In this example it may be obvious to create some string and send it in proper way. But how about more complex objects we are dealing with? Doesn't it force us to understand all those internal complex object requirements? Instead of mocking A.method(), now I need create A(B input), so need create B(C input), also create C?

Comment: The contract in example says "given source and response refferences the algorithm calculates SomeHow(!!) the result - a map of string to object. Thats what you should test IMO. Why is it important how exactly it does it internally as long as the result is correct. Maybe it uses assembly commands to directly access registers - who cares. I'm exaggerating of course, but at the and these are tests for correctness ( this is called functional testing).

Comment: It makes sense, I know most of the concepts but it still make me a little confused. One of the arguments we were referring for the those tests were avoiding testing complexity and increase testing readibility. But while we prepare those A, B, C objects I gave in the example, aren't we doing same complexity? In your comment ->  *your test will look like a long series of ***mocks*** and it will be hard to read/understand/maintain the test*, now it is like -> *your test will look like a long series of  ***required input objects*** and it will be hard to read/understand/maintain the test*

Comment: Not really, in your example you can prepare only the input parameters (by means of preparing a Stub or even creating a real object) and possible (not in your example) - mock the interactions in case the code goes to DB, does http request, etc. If an input parameter, say, Response is complicated and depends on other objects you don't really have to fully configure them as well, just provide a stub of Response. Its much better to work against interfaces in this case so that the stubs will be "clean" and you won't have to deal with their internal state. Hope I've addressed the A,B,C Example.